# 'list' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deployment, jupyter

I want to deploy a breast cancer detection ml model using flask.
here's the error:

```
File "C:\Users\sakshi sanket\Desktop\Breastcancer\app.py", line 22, in predict
    output = model.predict(df)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

here's the code:

app.py

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pickle


app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="template")
model = pickle.load(open('breast_cancer_detector.pickle', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    input_features = [float(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    features_value = [np.array(input_features)]

    features_name = ['id', 'diagnosis', 'radius_mean', 'texture_mean', 'perimeter_mean', 'area_mean', 'smoothness_mean', 'compactness_mean', 'concavity_mean', 'concave points_mean', 'symmetry_mean', 'fractal_dimension_mean', 'radius_se', 'texture_se', 'perimeter_se', 'area_se', 'smoothness_se', 'compactness_se', 'concavity_se', 'concave points_se', 'symmetry_se', 'fractal_dimension_se', 'radius_worst', 'texture_worst', 'perimeter_worst', 'area_worst', 'smoothness_worst', 'compactness_worst', 'concavity_worst', 'concave points_worst', 'symmetry_worst', 'fractal_dimension_worst']

    df = pd.DataFrame(features_value, columns=features_name)
    output = model.predict(df)
    
    if output == 0:
        res_val = "** breast cancer **"
    else:
        res_val = "no breast cancer"

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Patient has {}'.format(res_val)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port='8080', debug=True)
```

Please help me.

Comment: `model` is a list. You define it on the line `model = pickle.load(open('breast_cancer_detector.pickle', 'rb'))`. Try printing it to see what the contents of the list look like.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately there is no difference.Same error occurs.

Comment: your pickle is a `list` object as @MattKeane mentioned. Review how and what you save as a pickle.

Comment: We can't really help you since we can't examine `model`.  But the error is clear.  `model`, as loaded from the file is a Python `list`, not an object that has a `predict` method.  That list might contain a valid 'model' object, but the list itself is not one.  You have to explore that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try `output = model[0].predict(df)`. Since it is a list, using [0] should reference a single item.